# Why am I unable to calculate the date time difference using moment js in this example?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to calculate the time difference between start and end.

snippet using moment.js

```
cleanStartTime = i.time_start
cleanStartTime = moment(cleanStartTime).format('LLL')
cleanEndTime = i.time_end
cleanEndTime = moment(cleanEndTime).format('LLL')
theDuration = moment.duration(cleanStartTime.diff(cleanEndTime)).humanize()
console.log(theDuration)
```

error:

```
TypeError: cleanStartTime.diff is not a function
```

cleanStartTime looks like May 7, 2018 5:51 PM

Comment: What does console logging `cleanStartTime` right above `theDuration` output?

Comment: Is it a string? Did you try to remove the .format() functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are formatting your moment objects into string, and then trying to use methods from the original moment objects. If you look at a simple example

```
moment().format('LLL')
```

gives

```
"June 3, 2019 12:06 PM"
```

Which is a string and therefore doesn't have the diff method you're trying to use defined. Formatting your string after all the operations have been done (or not at all) should solve your problem. For example.

```
cleanStartTime = moment();
cleanEndTime = moment().add(100, 'days');
theDuration = moment.duration(cleanStartTime.diff(cleanEndTime)).humanize()
console.log(theDuration)
```

Gives what I suspect you  were originally looking for

```
3 months
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to `moment(cleanStartTime).diff(cleanEndTime)` instead of `cleanStartTime.diff(cleanEndTime)`, the error should disappear.